# How I can parse string double with "E" at the end?

Tags: c#, parsing, double, exponent

I have tried parsing the double like so:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
if (double.TryParse("9,27823508234186E", NumberStyles.Float, cultureInfo, out a))
   {...}
```

I can't use Math.Round. I used "." and ",", and I used different NumberStyles.
I tried to do this by adding "0" after "E", which works, but it's bad practice to add a zero every time.

Comment: Try following :             CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            info.NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = ","};

            double.TryParse("9,27823508234186E", NumberStyles.Float, info, out a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the TrimEnd() function on the string that you are parsing:

```
if (double.TryParse("9,27823508234186E".TrimEnd('E'), NumberStyles.Float, cultureInfo, out a))
   {...}
```

This will trim all "E" from the end of the string. Also, this will not throw any exceptions if you use it on a number that does not have "E" at the end. It will simply do nothing.

Comment: Hmm.. I dunno how good it is, but now this is the only way to solve it. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You can add it to any string that you want to parse as a double and it will not cause a problem if the string does not have "E" at the end so it is safe that way.

Comment: Thanks, I will use it.